# UI not binding to INotifyCollectionChanged

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, inotifycollectionchanged

I have some collection that implements INotifyCollectionChanged.

```cs
public sealed class GroupCollection : INotifyCollectionChanged, IList<Group>
{
    //...
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    private void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CollectionChanged != null)
        {
            CollectionChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

It is used in xaml

```cs
        <CollectionViewSource x:Name="groupedItemsViewSource" Source="{Binding Groups}"/>
```

then in xaml.cs

```cs
        this.DefaultViewModel["Groups"] = groups.GroupCollection;
```

Collection items are displayed just fine. But UI does not subscribe to `CollectionChanged` and doesn't updates itself when `CollectionChanged` is fired. Maybe I need to implement more interfaces to make UI control subscribe to event?

P.S. I cannot use ObservableCollection because compiler says that this "is not a Windows Runtime interface".

Answer (score 0):

The following use of `ObservableCollection` works fine for me when using the default Grid application template:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
...
class MyOC : ObservableCollection<SampleDataGroup> { };
...
var oc = new MyOC();
string id = "title1";
oc.Add(new SampleDataGroup(id, id, id, "", id));
id = "title2";
oc.Add(new SampleDataGroup(id, id, id, "", id));
this.DefaultViewModel["Groups"] = oc;
```

I would guess that you could do something similar in your project:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
...
public sealed class GroupCollection : ObservableCollection<Group>
{
...
```

Comment: I cannot do this. `GroupCollection` is located inside another project (project type is "Windows Runtime Component"). Public class inside "Windows Runtime Component" cannot implement `ObservableCollection`. If I try, I get compilation error "`ObservableCollection` is not a Windows Runtime interface".